# git: work with git-svn when there are merges

Tags: git, svn

As far as I understand, git-svn does not support pushing merge commits.

Is there a way to make it work with such commits?

We have tried to use rebase to create a linear history. However, this fails with conflicts on whitespace errors. Is there a way of linearizing the history so there are no conflicts?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of rebasing merged commits to svn is to squash them:

assuming we rebase branch `dev` to `trunk`

```
git checkout trunk
git merge --squash dev
```

you might have to fix real merge conflicts between `trunk` and `dev`. At the end you have one commit which you can well `git svn dcommit`.

The downside of this method is that you loose granularity of your commits in SVN. If this is a problem, you could employ a rebase-style merging strategy for git (e.g. http://unethicalblogger.com/2010/04/02/a-rebase-based-workflow.html ).

Answer (score 0):

It's not straightforward, but possible.

1. Check out your feature branch

   ```
   $ git checkout feature1
   ```
2. Create a Subversion branch, preferrably with the same name and rebase your local git branch

   ```
   $ git svn branch feature1
   $ git rebase remotes/feature1
   ```
3. When you push your changes, they will go to the Subversion branch, not to the trunk.

   ```
   $ git svn dcommit
   ```

The only way to do e merge that I am aware of is using a temporary SVN checkout and using `svn merge`. For merges that can be performed automatically, without conflicts, scripting the last steps (SVN repository lookup, temporary checkout, merge) has worked well for me.